# Clean Architecture: UseCase Output Port

Tags: oop, architecture, solid-principles, clean-architecture, design-principles

I have a question regarding the "Use Case Output Port" in Uncle Bob´s  [Clean Architecture](https://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html).

In the image, Uncle Bob describes the port as an interface. I am wondering if it *has* to be that way or if the invoked Use Case Interactor could also return a "simple" value. In either case the Application and Business Rules Layer would define its interface that the Interface Adapters Layer has to use. So I think for simple invocations just returning a value would not violate the architectural idea.

Is that true?

Additionally, I think this Output Port Interface implemented by the presenter should work like the Observer pattern. The presenter simply observes the interactor for relevant "events". In the case of .NET where events are first-class citizens, I think using one of these is the same idea.

Are these thoughts compatible with the ideas behind Clean Architecture?

Answer (score 1):

Howzit OP. I see your question is still unanswered after all these years and I hope we can reason about this and provide some clarity. I also hope I am understanding your question correctly. So with that in mind, here is how I see the solution:

The short answer is, a use case interactor should be able to return a simple value (by which I assume string, int, bool etc) without breaking any architectural rules.

If we go over the onion architecture, which is very similar to the clean architecture, the idea is to encapsulate the core business logic in the center of the architecture, the domain. The corresponding concept in the clean architecture is the entities and the use cases on top of it. We do this because we want to dictate our understanding of the business in a consistent way when we write our business rules.

The interface adapters allow us to convert the outside world to our understanding. What we want is a contract in our domain (use cases or entities) that ensures we will get what we need from the outside world, without knowing any implementation details. We also don't care what the outside world calls it, we convert their understanding to ours.

A common way to do this, is to define the interface in the domain to establish a contract that says, we expect to give "x", and you must then tell us what "y" is. The implementation can then sit outside the domain.

Now to get to the core of your question. Let's assume that the core of our application is to track some complicated process with various stages. During one of these stages, we need to send data to a couple of external parties and we want to keep a reference of some sort for auditing purposes. In such a case our interface may sit in the domain and state we send our complicated object to some party, and we expect a string reference back. We can then use this string reference and fire some domain event etc. The implementation can sit completely outside of the domain and call external APIs and do it's thing, but our core domain is unaffected. Hence returning a simple value has no impact on the architecture. The reverse of the above scenario may also hold true. We can say that we have a reference id of some sort, and the outside world needs to return us our understanding of some object.

For the second part of your question. I would imagine it depends on the use case itself. If you present some idea out there and need to constantly react to it, domain events will get involved and you will have a structure very similar to the observer pattern. .NET encapsulates events very nicely and fits very well with clean architecture and Domain driven design.

Please let me know if the above makes sense or if I can clarify it in any way.